# Как добавить элементу массива стили?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Хочу добавить `div`'у с классом `param-count` определенные стили. Но добавляя их через элемент массива, получаю ошибку:

> Uncaught TypeError: param[1].css is not a function

```js
var param = document.querySelectorAll('.view-list .param-count');
param[1].css({
    'position': 'absolute',
    'width': 'auto',
    'left': '120px',
    'bottom': '46px'
});
```

```html
<div class="view-list">
    <div class="param-count"></div>
    <div class="param"></div>
    <div class="param-count"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('.view-list .param-count').eq(1).css({
  'position': 'absolute',
  'width': 'auto',
  'left': '120px',
  'bottom': '46px'
});
```

Comment: @Regent, согласен, добавил.